# Sound doesn't work on a Dell Vostro 3400, shows up as unclaimed

Tags: sound, drivers, hardware

I have no sound since installing Ubuntu 11.10 on my Dell Vostro 3400. It looks like the HDMI sound card is found, but not the card that would make sound come out of my speakers.

This is what appears to be the relevant output from lshw:

```
 *-multimedia UNCLAIMED
             description: Audio device
             product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 06
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:fbe00000-fbe03fff
```

It is funny as the sound "just worked" with Fedora 13-15, but not with Ubuntu 11.10 out of the box.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your kernel does not recognise your soundcard

Try the following command and reboot

```
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-generic
```

---

*Sources* : http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-763241.html